# How to extract the last run of a test from a log in python

Tags: python, automated-tests

I've been tasked with automating the extraction of a particular log file. The log captures a PC booting up and running a test before power cycling. This is the gist of what the test looks like each time it runs:

```
Test 1 ------------>PASSED
Test 2 ------------>PASSED
Test 3 ------------>PASSED
...
```

I need to extract the **last** run of this test in the log, as that is most likely the one where the test is a "good run" and passes. Does anyone have any good ways on how to approach this?

My initial strategy was to parse the file looking for each test name and the string "PASSED" in the same line. But I'm not sure how to isolate the **last** run from the rest of the earlier runs

Comment: If the tests are in order, why not traverse the lines of the file from the end until the first time you retrieve the line you need?

Comment: @Zionsof that's a good idea! I didn't think of that.. I was wondering if maybe something like a stack or queue made sense to use here. Personally I didn't, but I was curious

Comment: I think it's an overkill to use any of them if you're looking for just one line. I'd say traverse the lines from the end until you encounter what you need and stop there